# Helps to repair true or false condition when comparing a word with text

Tags: java

I split the text to form words and wanted to compare it to a String and then return the false value to the true if the word is found in the text. My problem is that when checking using the equals () method it always returns me false. saying that the message is not in the text. How can I fix this?

```
      String test = "Today will go to rainning";
    String words = "go";

    String[] arrayWords = test.split(" ");
    boolean verify = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayWords.length; i++) 

       if (arrayWords[i].equals(words)) {
           verify = true;                 
            System.out.println("This word find in text");            
            break;
        } else {
             verify = false;
            System.out.println("This word not find in text.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

System.out.println("This word not find in text.");

Comment: Just read your code and think about what your code would do when the first item doesn't match. Would your code bother to check the second item?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
break in else needs to be removed
verify = false;
System.out.println("This word not find in text.");
break;
since after first comparison it will come out of loop with false printed.
keep a boolean variable and set it to true in if block and print the 
answer based on that and we can keep the break in if
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are doing the 'break;' on the else condition, which is wrong.

Also, make sure you open brackets in your for loop (is not needed, but will help you to prevent some future bug if you add more lines to the for cycle) :

```
  String test = "Today will go to rainning";
  String words = "go";

  String[] arrayWords = test.split(" ");
  boolean verify = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayWords.length; i++) {
     if (arrayWords[i].equals(words)) {
        verify = true;
        break;
     } 
  }

  if (verify) {
     System.out.println("This word find in text");
  } else {
     System.out.println("This word not find in text.");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nel. Its works. But i have a doubt when a condition of false she repeats another 4 times the sentence. how can i stop this? I know that by System.exit (0) it exits the program and only gives once. but is there any way just to repeat it once?

Comment: Didn't realize that was the behavior your were looking for. Just edited the code to make it as you want. The way it is right now, the verify boolean is false by default and is only set as true when something is found. At the end of the for cycle, you will check the value of the verify boolean and print the message according to it.

Comment: Thanks @Nel I got it working I had not seen the verify method so I was doing the same screw up.